# Show preview posts and pages to clients

Tags: pages, previews

My clients wants to see the changes i have made in his wordpress site before publishing.

Is it a good method, paste the page preview link to show to him? Of course this method only works if we are both logged in the Panel Administration. Otherwise what how do you recommend to do? I can not physically meet up my client so that's why i need a solution.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password-protect and publish the page and send your client the password.

Comment: But the content goes live in this way, i probably miss something in your explanation?

Comment: If you password-protect your page, no one can see it without the password, and if your settings disallow search engine crawling, then it's not an issue. This is assuming that your changes are on draft pages, which can also be returned to draft once the review is complete. Your other option is to give the client a login so he can see the preview, which you mentioned.

Comment: ah allright now it's clear, i am going to try this technique. Thanks.